# Working with GTFS data, "spatial grid index size invalid"

Tags: arcgis-desktop, general-transit-feed-specification

I have been attempting to build a network analysis based on GTFS data for the Netherlands. I have obtained this data from transitfeeds.com (OVapi GTFS for the Netherlands), and am working with Esri's Add GTFS to a network Dataset extension (http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=0fa52a75d9ba4abcad6b88bb6285fae1). I have managed to Generate to transit lines and stops, but when I try to use the tool to Generate Stop-Street Connectors I repeatedly receive a message saying that "The spatial index grid size is invalid".

I have deleted and recreated the spatial index as suggested by Esri (http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/modifying-a-spatial-index.htm), but it does not solve the problem. All features related have the same spatial index, both before and after this recreation.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to ensure the data is projected into a non geographic coordinate system. This sort of message may appear because a grid of geographic coordinates may require too much precision or digits after the decimal.

Try reprojecting both the GTFS and OSM into one of the projections suggested here https://epsg.io/?q=Netherlands

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, it did not work and I still receive the same error and am still looking for a viable solution. Otherwise, is there any way I might be able to find out if the reason is actually this issue of possibly something else which the error message does not comment about?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a bit old but I had the same problem and found a solution that worked for me and maybe it will help others that come across this thread.

I had also tried to delete the spatial index as well as reprojecting the data into a non-geographic coordinate system but the error remained despite both of these changes.

Upon more closely inspecting my GTFS data I noticed that there were some stops that were placed near (0,0). When I deleted these stops from the layer, the tool worked without any error. I'm not sure exactly what caused the problem, but if you have a similar situation with some misplaced or undefined stops in your GTFS data, deleting them may help!